# Does order of columns of Multi-Column Indexes in where clause in MySQL matter?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-performance

I have a table below:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` ( 
     `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
     `age`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`city`) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to know, if I execute the following two SQLs, do they have the same performance?

```
mysql> select * from student where name='John' and city='NewYork';
mysql> select * from student where city='NewYork' and name='John';
```

Involved question:

1. If there is a multi-column indexes (name, city), do the two SQLs all use it?
2. Does the optimizer change the second sql to the first because of the index?

I execute explain on the two of them, the result is below:

```
mysql> explain select * from student where name='John' and city='NewYork';
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+

| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+

|  1 | SIMPLE      | student | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 184     | const,const |    1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
```

mysql> explain select * from student where city='NewYork' and name='John';

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+

|  1 | SIMPLE      | student | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 184     | const,const |    1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: The order of columns in a multi-column index matters. An index on columns `name` and `city` can be used instead of an index on column `name` but it cannot be used instead of an index on column `city`. The order of conditions in the `WHERE` clause doesn't matter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You did a good job asking your first question.

Comment: Index cookbook:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of columns in a multi-column index matters.

The documentation of the [multiple-column indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) reads:

> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same table.

This means an index on columns `name` and `city` can be used when an index on column `name` is needed but it cannot be used instead of an index on column `city`.

The order of conditions in the `WHERE` clause doesn't matter. The MySQL optimizer [does a lot of work](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html) on the conditions on the `WHERE` clause to eliminate as many candidate rows as possible as early as possible and to read as little data as possible from the tables and indexes (because some of the read data is dropped because it doesn't match the entire `WHERE` clause).

Answer (score 6):

> If, given an index on `(name,city)`, I execute the following two SQLs, do they have the same performance?
>
> `where name='John' and city='NewYork'`
>
> `where city='NewYork' and name='John'`

Yes.

The query planner doesn't care about the order of `WHERE` clauses. If both your clauses filter on equality, the planner can use the index. SQL is a *declarative* language, not *procedural.* That is, you say *what you want*, not *how to get it.* It's a little counterintuitive for many programmers.

It can also use the `(name,city)` index for `WHERE name LIKE 'Raymo%'` because `name` is first in the index.  It cannot use that index for `WHERE city = 'Kalamazoo'`, though.

It can use the index for `WHERE city LIKE 'Kalam%' AND name = 'Raymond'`. In that case it uses the index to find the name value, then scans for matching cities.

If you had an index on  `(city,name)` you could also use that for `WHERE city = 'Kalamazoo' AND name = 'Raymond'`.  If both indexes exist, the query planner will pick one, probably based on some kind of cardinality consideration.

Note. If instead you have two different indexes on `city` and `name`, the query planner can't (as of mid-2017) use more than one of them to satisfy `WHERE city = 'Kalamazoo' AND name = 'Raymond'`.

http://use-the-index-luke.com/  for good info.